# VBA merging cells in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to merge cells in a first column. In that column cells (1,1)-(3,1) contain information, then I have several empty cells and after that more cells with data. I want to merge all empty cells with the previous cell that isn't empty. My code works for only first block of empty cells and on the second block I have error 5941 'The requested member of the collection does not exist.'

```
Sub Merge()
    Dim count As Integer
    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1,1).Select
    Selection.SelectColumn
    count = 0
    For Each acell In Selection.Cells
        count = count + 1
        If Asc(acell.Range.Text) = 13 Then
            acell.Merge _
            MergeTo:=ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(count - 1, 1)
            count = count - 1
        End If
    Next acell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`For Each acell In Selection.Cells`

This statement iterates through the indexed collection of cells. When you merge two cells the index doesn't get updated, which causes the error you are getting.

Whenever you do an operation that results in an item being deleted from a collection you should iterate through that collection in reverse. For example:

```
For idx = Selection.Cells.Count to 1 step -1
    'do something here
Next idx
```

This way your code is maintaining the index and will remain correct.